# Java JSF: Editing rows in a dataTable tag

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to update a row in a JSF data table based on the method in this article: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-update-row-in-jsf-datatable/

When I click Save, I am getting this error message:

**Conversion Error setting value '1970-09-08' for 'null Converter'.**

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Markup:

```
<h:form>
                        <h:commandButton action="addEmployee" value="Add New" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <br />

                        <h:dataTable class="table table-striped" value="#{employeeCollection.items}" var="item">
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                                <h:commandButton action="#{employeeCollection.edit(item)}" value="Edit" class="btn" rendered="#{not item.isEditing}" />
                                <h:commandButton action="#{employeeCollection.save(item)}" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" rendered="#{item.isEditing}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                                <h:inputText value="#{item.firstName}" rendered="#{item.isEditing}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.firstName}" rendered="#{not item.isEditing}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
                                <h:inputText value="#{item.lastName}" rendered="#{item.isEditing}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}" rendered="#{not item.isEditing}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Date of Birth</f:facet>
                                <h:inputText value="#{item.dateOfBirth}" rendered="#{item.isEditing}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.dateOfBirth}" rendered="#{not item.isEditing}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
```

I would post the managed bean code, but I don't think that's necessary because when clicking the Save button, the save(item) function never seems to be called anyway... so it must be something else. I am new to Java, so probably I'm forgetting something very basic here, somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error describes that there was an error converting the `String` using a `null` converter. This happens if you use a `Date` object in your `<h:inputText>` tag component without a `DateTime` converter. You can fix this by changing the JSF code:

```html
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Date of Birth</f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{item.dateOfBirth}" rendered="#{item.isEditing}">
        <!-- adding the datetime converter -->
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.dateOfBirth}" rendered="#{not item.isEditing}" />
</h:column>
```

Still, it's not a good approach to handle the date validations for you and your user. It would be better to use a third party library that provides you a Calendar component like [PrimeFaces Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarBasic.jsf) or [RichFaces Calendar](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar).

Note that you can use the JSF provided converters for DateTime and Numbers, and you can create your custom data converters. More info:

- [Custom Converter in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)
- [Custom converter JSF 2 with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11613134/1065197)
- [Generic JSF entity converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4268179/1065197)

Comment: +1 for solution and making us aware about approach "PrimeFaces and RIchFaces Calendar"