# How to get attribute value in JSP custom tags

Tags: java, jsp, converters

I have a JSP custom tag defined as below:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://sp.com/customConverterTaglib</namespace>
        <tag>
            <tag-name>BigDecimalConverter</tag-name>
            <converter>
                <converter-id>BigDecimalConverter</converter-id>
            </converter>
            <attribute>
                <name>pattern</name>
                <required>false</required>
                <type>java.lang.String</type>
            </attribute>
        </tag> 
</facelet-taglib>
```

And I'm trying to use it in my XHTML page:

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:o="http://sp.com/customConverterTaglib">
    <!-- ... -->

    <h:inputText id="weightId" value="#{backingBeanRef['currentObject']}">
        <o:BigDecimalConverter pattern="###,##0.000"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <!-- ... -->
 </ui:composition>
```

And this is my BigDecimalConverter class:

```
 @FacesConverter( value="BigDecimalConverter")
 public class BigDecimalConverter implements Converter {

        private String pattern;

        public BigDecimalConverter() {

        }

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext,
                UIComponent uiComponent, String param) {
                //things...
        }

        public String getPattern() {
            return pattern;
        }

        public void setPattern(String pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }
   }
```

When the method is running, in debug mode I'm watching that pattern attribute is null. Where is the mistake? Why I'm not getting the pattern attribute properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613134/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-with-arguments

Comment: @RC. I'm not using JSF converter, this is my own converter.

Comment: read the linked question and answer again please

Comment: @RC. are you making reference to the lefloh answer?